Recursively traverse Pandas Dataframe
There is Pandas dataframe
    id  parent_id   result
    1   0           True
    2   0           False
    3   1           True
    4   1           False
    5   2           True
    6   2           False
    7   4           True
    8   4           True

How to recursively traverse the entire frame, while
if the node contains descendants, then i need to do "OR" operation for all descendants rows,and do "AND" operation for this intermediate result and parent row? i.e.
AND(parent['result'], OR (descendants['result']))

So i need  get result of this  boolean expression:
df.loc[df['id'] == 1, 'result'] AND
 (df.loc[df['id'] == 3, 'result'] OR 
   (
    df.loc[df['id'] == 4, 'result'] 
    AND 
      (
              df.loc[df['id'] == 7, 'result'] OR
              df.loc[df['id'] == 8, 'result']
      ) 
  ) 
 ) 
 
OR 
(
  df.loc[df['id'] == 2, 'result']
  AND (
              df.loc[df['id'] == 5, 'result'] OR 
              df.loc[df['id'] == 6, 'result']
      ) 

)


How looks expected output?

@jezrael, i edited post

I think you need to create a recursive function to process each row on its parent_id and identify all the descendants in a row and recursively process them. Then perform an OR operation across all descendant rows' result values. Combine the current row result with the OR result of descendants using AND. Next is to iterate over the DataFrame and apply the recursive function to each row starting from root nodes; And finally store the result back in the DataFrame under the same column.

Using dataframe from OP:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        "parent_id": [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
        "result": [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True],
    }
)

Solution:
def traverse(df, id):
    parent_result = df[df["id"] == id]["result"].iloc[0]
    children = df[df["parent_id"] == id]
    if children.empty:
        return parent_result
    return parent_result and children["id"].apply(lambda x: traverse(df, x)).any()

root_ids = df[df["parent_id"] == 0]["id"]
out = root_ids.apply(lambda x: traverse(df, x)).any()

Output:
True


You could use a graph approach with networkx, build the graph and check the parent and descendants:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent_id', target='id',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# nodes that are True: {1, 3, 5, 7, 8}
trues = set(df.loc[df['result'], 'id'])
# parents: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 4}
parents = df.set_index('id')['parent_id'].to_dict()

def check(G):
    for k, lst in nx.dfs_successors(G).items():
        if not (parents.get(k) or any(x in trues for x in lst)):
            return False
    return True

out = check(G)

Output: True
Graph (blue = True ; red = False):

